# Dynamic ansible host_vars

Tags: ansible

I have a use case for a play where the installation path for tomcat changes based on the hostname and the value of a variable.  Not sure how to handle this.  For example, I have the following inventory:

[servers]
server1
server2
server3

I have a global_var that specifies the type of platform for my install like so:
platform: training

My platform variable could be set to training, production, development

Based on the value of platform and the hostname, my tomcat installation path will be different, so I can't just have:

host_vars/server1.yml
tomcat_path: /somepath1
host_vars/server2.yml
tomcat_path: /somepath2
host_vars/server3.yml
tomcat_path: /somepath3

I'm looking to do something akin too:

server1.yml
tomcat_path: /somepath1
when: "{{ platform }} == training"
tomcat_path: /somepath2
when: "{{ platform }} == production"
tomcat_path: /somepath3
when: "{{ platform }} == development"

How do you handle such a case in ansible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could define all possible platform-tomcat_path options in a dictionary variable, and then select the desired combination with several ways.

check below example (with 3 different ways to reference the variables):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    tomcat_path: { training: /somepath1, production: /somepath2, development: /somepath3 }
    your_selected_mode: development


  tasks:

  - name: print
    debug:
      var: tomcat_path.training

  - name: print
    debug:
      var: tomcat_path['production']

  - name: print
    debug:
      var: tomcat_path.{{your_selected_mode}}
```

you can use the `your_selected_mode` to select the mode you need.

output:

```
TASK [print] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tomcat_path.training": "/somepath1"
}

TASK [print] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tomcat_path['production']": "/somepath2"
}

TASK [print] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "tomcat_path.development": "/somepath3"
}
```

if needed to further customize it per host, you can have this `tomcat_path` variable declaration in the `host_vars` file and alter it to fit your needs.

Comment: Hmm...I like that.  I've been trying to implement via conditional includes right now. So, include_vars: vars/tomcat_dev.yml when: platform.development  Is there a preferred way to do this or is either fine?

Comment: With your way requires to add the extra task to load the files, with the proposed way they are automatically available. but all in all, i would say if both work => both are fine?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [conditional imports](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditional-imports) but it requires you to have one variables file per host and platform:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_files:
   - "vars/{{ inventory_hostname }}_{{ platform }}.yml"
  tasks:
   - name: echo path
     debug: msg="Tomcat path is {{ tomcat_path }}"
```

You would need to define the variable files `vars/server1_training.yml, vars/server2_training.yml, vars/server3_training.yml, vars/server1_production.yml, ...`.